Problemas al actualizar mi jdk en windows 10
Tengo un problema al actualizar mi JDK: Yo fui a ajustes y fui y al panel de control, para actualizar mi JDK a uno mayor, para poder instalarme netbeans 17 que utiliza JDK 21, pues yo fui al panel de control y le di a java y a actualizar, pero me sale el siguiente error:

No si se podrá actualizar en otro sitio, y ademas, sin poder actualizar mi jdk, no podre descargar netbeans 17, si alguien sabe algo que responda en los comentarios, porfavor, porque quiero comenzar mi app lo antes posible, gracias de antemano.

Intentaste desinstalar todas las versiones anteriores de Java, y reiniciar tu PC antes de instalar el JDK, como se explica en este enlace?

Ahorita me da pereza escribirte una respuesta, pero hallé esto: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.html

Si, pero no me funciona, sale el mismo mensaje de error

Gracias por la ayuda, pero segui todos los pasos, y el mismo error
